# Why custom DbContext throws exception 'The entity type ApplicationUser is not part of the model for the current context'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I know this looks like a duplicate, but I am having a question as to why and not how?

I have following line of code which tries to use Userstore to get a valid user.

```
var _context = new JobContext();
var _userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(_context));
var user = await _userManager.FindAsync(context.UserName, context.Password);
```

And I get this error,

> The entity type ApplicationUser is not part of the model for the current context.

Now my job context looks like,

```
public class JobContext : DbContext//IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>//
{
    public DbSet<Job> Jobs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<JobHistory> JobHistory { get; set; }

    public JobContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<JobContext>(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<JobContext>());
    }
}
```

So from the error what I understand is, User store is not able to find a `DbSet<ApplicationUser>` and therefore it fails to query an Application User.

Now If I just tweak the one line of code, to use `ApplicationDbContext` and not `JobContext', it works fine.

```
var _context = new ApplicationDbContext();
var _userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(_context));
var user = await _userManager.FindAsync(context.UserName, context.Password);
```

When I browse to ApplicationDbContext, here is what we have.

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("JobContext", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}

public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }
}
```

Now ApplicationDbContext has interface IdentityDbContext but I do not understand how does this work! Because, if I do the same thing with JobContext,(to implement IdentityDbContext), it does not work.

```
public class JobContext : IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>
```

Comment: @SlavaUtesinov, Please go through the question again. I am already using ApplicationDbContext and want to know the implementation difference.

Comment: You have `JobContext : IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>` instead of `JobContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>`